# Binary Integer Program Solver for Java

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization

My problem is in trying to solve a Binary Integer Program through Java.  I want to run a series of experiments and an integral component of these experiments is to solve an integer program where the variables are constrained to be between 0 and 1.

In the past I have solved such problems in MatLab, with the function [bintprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/bintprog.html).  In the search for such a function (or class? I'm very new to Java) to use in Java, I have come up empty handed.

**Is there a Java library available to solve Integer Programs that has really good documentation?**

In my search, I have seen suggestions to use a package called [LP_Solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) that has had a Java wrapper built around it, and a similar wrapper built for a package called [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) (wrappers [here](http://glpk-java.sourceforge.net/) and [here](http://bjoern.dapnet.de/glpk/)) (which I have used before).  The problem with these tools is that they are not strictly designed for Java, and thusly, lack the kind of documentation that I feel I need, and even worse have complicated instructions to even begin using them in my own code.  As I am currently learning the Java language I am wondering if there are any really good packages available to solve Binary Integer Programs, Mixed Integer Linear Programs, or just Integer Programs from my own Java code.

As a side note, I really do not want to switch to another language because I am building off of past code and classes that perform the tasks I desire.

Comment: Java is general-purpose language.  MatLab is a mathematics programming language.  You will need to roll your own functionality, or find a 3rd-party library to do your calculations.

Comment: So, you are looking for a Java version of MATLAB's [`bigintprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/bintprog.html)?

Comment: @Matt Ball  That is exactly what I am looking for.  A library that will do the trick and that has good documentation on how to implement the procedure.  Thank you for the opportunity to clarify my question.

Comment: @Walter: then you should clarify your question to say that. Remove the chaff, and ask what you mean.

Comment: @Matt  Does my latest edit improve the quality of my question?  I want to be sure that people can get to the heart of my question, but still have the ability to see some of the background for it.

Comment: Have you looked at http://javailp.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: Take a look into apache.commons.math. Maybe it has what you need: http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/optimization.html

Comment: @Mark Elliot  I have not, but will as soon as I am back from class.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LP_Solve with the Java wrapper** is what I will be using.  It is a free Mixed Integer Linear Program solver.  LP_Solve for Java is very easy to install following these **[instructions](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/)**.  Included in the packages you download are files with lots of example code, which I have found useful.  The only part of the installation that slowed me down was having to join the [Yahoo group](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) to find the files for download.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Java Integer Linear Program Solver (JILPS)](http://code.google.com/p/jilps/)?

Comment: I was really hopeful about this, but JILPS does not seem to be a complete project.  It seems more like a working project with no available downloads or related information.  Thank you though, and please feel free to correct me if I am missing something obvious in the link!

Comment: @Walter: It seems like the code is well-documented, but you'll have to do a checkout rather than a download. For an example, see this test program: http://code.google.com/p/jilps/source/browse/trunk/src/jilps/cop4j/TestSimplexMethodPrimal.java

Answer (score 0):

IBM cplex even though being c library has java wrappers and documentation

Answer (score -1):

if you want values 0 or 1 try the bool datatype...if your looking at probabilities (that lie between 0 to 1)try limiting a float value such that it is >= 0 and <=1;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it really does not address my question.  I have edited my question to try and clarify what I am looking for.